# MSSQL insert into table from different server behind different vpn

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, vpn, database-backups

So I have 2 mssql servers, 2 databases. Each server is behind different VPN. I'am connected to both of them at the same time and I can sucessfully connect to both servers in SSMS at the same time.
However when I try to add 'Linked server' it throws me out connection failed error.
Code I currently have:

```
INSERT INTO
  TARGETTABLE
  SELECT TOP 5
   *
  FROM 
    [CONNECTEDSERVERIP].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] AS t2
  ORDER BY
    t2.id
```

Any way to perform that without need to backup table and restore on target server?

Comment: There are no miracles available here. If the 2 machines cannot be seen, then the short answer is no. You have a basic ETL situation that involves a more complicated problem of overcoming a networking issue. Get your team together and discuss the issue and possible solutions within the limitations of your infrastructure.

Comment: Have you checked any required ports are open

Comment: That you can connect to them only proves your machine can connect to both servers; it says nothing about whether the machines can connect to each other. Linked servers are a bit of a maintenance headache, convenient as they might seem; think twice before going that way as opposed to writing client software that connects to instances separately. Notably, SSMS also offers an import/export feature that's quite speedy and does work across servers as long as you can connect to them.